# Math.cos(Math.radians(90)) doesn't give 0

Tags: java

The following line of code:

```
System.out.println( Math.cos( Math.toRadians(90) ) );
```

prints `6.123233995736766E-17`.

It should print `0`. What's wrong?

Comment: Floating point inaccuracy. 10^-17 is close enough to zero for most practical purposes.

Comment: Identical to several other questions here on SO, nearly-identical to many more, and similar, in its misunderstanding of floating-point numbers to many, many, many other questions.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is to check against some allowable tolerance. For example, let `num=Math.cos( Math.toRadians(90) )`. `if(Math.abs(num - 0)) < 1E-8) // num is suffiently close to zero`.

Comment: @nneonneo In a 2D game I'm making this makes a difference. What do you suggest I do?

Comment: @nneonneo _Is_ 10^-17 close to zero?  That depends...  It is _very_ close to zero compared to the range of the cos(x) function, so in this case the answer probably would be yes, but there are applications (e.g., high-energy physics experiments) in which 10^-17 might be considered to be much greater than zero.

Comment: `System.out.println(0);`. All kidding aside, if there's some reason why you need the result to be zero under certain conditions, write a logical expression that describes what those conditions are, and set your result directly to 0.0 when that expression returns true; call the `Math.cos` function only when those conditions are false. You can also treat results close to 0 the same as zero (by using `Math.abs` as suggested earlier) if it is OK for conditions that are _almost_ indentical to your "90-degree" condition to trigger whatever the 90-degree condition is supposed to trigger.

Comment: @Prog: I have difficulty believing that an error of 10^-17 can have any effect on a 2D game. The error would have to compound *seriously* for it to even remotely affect your game. You'll have to explain *why* you think it makes a difference.

Comment: @jameslarge: Notice I said "most practical purposes". I'm aware that specialist applications may require more than 17 digits of precision. However, these applications would *clearly* not be using 64-bit floats, because their numbers would not be accurately representable.

Comment: @nneonneo, If a "specialist application" needs more than 17 digits of precision, it's _not_ because of the magnitude of the numbers.  A double on the order of 1.0e-17 carries just as many digits of precision as a double on the order of 1.0e200.